# Rails Server Error Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, uri, server-side

In my Rails app, I want to check if a redirect works correctly, and if it doesn't, then redirect to some other page that I know will work. Essentially, I have a line that says

```
redirect_to("somesite")
```

and if the redirect works, it will take me there, but if it doesn't, I get a response like:

```
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) ERROR URI::InvalidURIError
```

I tried using rescue block that catches the URI::InvalidURIError, but the error is thrown and never reaches the rescue block. Though what I'm doing may be a little unorthodox, I was wondering if there was a way to grab the error message of "ERROR URI::InvalidURIError" from the server and use that information to write conditions in my code? Thanks!

Comment: "I want to check if a redirect" are you doing this by testing (Rspec - or any other test methods)? where did you place your redirect_to ?

Comment: I am not using any tests, just rails server and my browser with the redirect_to in the controller. I originally had it like a begin and rescue block in one of my controller actions. gavin's answer worked out for me in getting a valid URI though, but thanks for replying anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate your url before the redirect_to action.

for example

```
url = "somesite"
if valid? uri
  redirect_to uri
else
  #handler
end

private
def valid?(uri)
  !!URI.parse(uri)
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  false
end
```